# Работа с базой данных, сохранение истории вносимых изменений в складе и ее редактирование

Tags: php, mysql

В 1с есть возможность оприходовать товар, потом сохраняется это оприходование от дельно и его можно отменить или изменить. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это реализовать в php, как сохранить оприходование понятно более менее, но как сделать, что бы можно было в истории оприходований зайти в нужное и внести в него правки, так чтоб оно полностью отменилось и создалось новое не знаю. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Никаких правок. Нужно исправить - создаётся новая запись с правильными значениями, старая помечается как неактуальная и в дальнейших операциях не участвует. Если требуется полное удаление - запись помечается неактуальной, а новая не создаётся. Теперь, игнорируя пометку неактуальности, можно поднять всю историю записи. А итоговые значения - считаются на основании значений актуальных записей.